# .Environment variables don't work in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, environment-variables

I have .env file in the root of my project in Vue3. In the components folder, I have Card.vue and this code

```
console.log(process.env.FOO)
```

But in browser, it shows undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables must start with `VUE_APP`, hence

```
`VUE_APP_FOO`
```

Comment: It shows this 'VUE_APP_FOO' is not defined while running npm run serve

Comment: Please, first change name of the variable to `VUE_APP_FOO` in .env file, and then refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Having a similar problem here. I'm usnig `VUE_APP_FOO` to set the variable in `.env` but it's still undefined when `console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_FOO)`.
Using Vue2 (Vue cli 4.5.11)

Comment: In my case solved checking for a annoying misspelling and restarting. @ToklCz try `console.log(process.env)` for debugging